# How can I get ansible to only install MySQL if it's being run via Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Our actual setup runs on AWS where we have RDS available, but in vagrant we naturally need to install MySQL locally. What's the normal way of skipping installation with Vagrant? My ansible file looks something like this:

```
---
- name: foo
  hosts: foo
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - common-web
    - bennojoy.mysql
    - php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having specific groups in your inventory file, and run an 'install locally' playbook on the vagrant instances. This also means you would want to run an 'install RDS config' playbook on the AWS instances of course...

Trying to do all the things in all the places in one playbook is possible, but imo its cleaner to have different playbooks for different environments.

Comment: This is basically what I do nowdays. In my role I'll have tags: `local-only` if there's some specific thing I must skip. Then I have different playbooks for different environments. It may become a problem to maintain if there's are frequent changes to the playbook, but so far it has been fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, as the vagrant always created a directory on the root level "/vagrant"

So just check it like this:

```
---
- name: foo
  hosts: foo
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - common-web
    - bennojoy.mysql
    - php

  tasks:
    - name: Check that /vagrant directory exist
      command: /usr/bin/test -e /vagrant
      register: dir_exists

  roles:
    - common-web
    - { role: bennojoy.mysql, when: when: dir_exists.rc == 0 }
    - php
```

Here I am supposing that "bennojoy.mysql" is your main mysql role, please check it and let me know if it work for you. Thanks